# Azure Sphere SDK Preview for Visual Studio failed

Tags: azure, azure-sphere

I recently tried to install the Azure Sphere SDK preview but it failed.  I have Visual Studio 2019 installed on my laptop running Windows 10.  Below are the logs:

```
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i001: Burn v3.11.0.1701, Windows v10.0 (Build 17763: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Temp\{84AB4C8B-BB5C-46E5-8C18-853A5F0D7022}\.cr\Azure_Sphere_SDK_Preview_for_Visual_Studio (1).exe
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i000: Initializing string variable 'MbaNetfxPackageId' to value 'netfxfullredist_43'
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i000: Initializing string variable 'vsixQuiet' to value 'yes'
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i009: Command Line: '"-burn.clean.room=C:\Users\Peter\Downloads\Azure_Sphere_SDK_Preview_for_Visual_Studio (1).exe" -burn.filehandle.attached=704 -burn.filehandle.self=708'
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\Peter\Downloads\Azure_Sphere_SDK_Preview_for_Visual_Studio (1).exe'
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'C:\Users\Peter\Downloads\'
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_VC_AzureSphere_20190609111327.log'
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i052: Condition '(VersionNT >= v6.1)' evaluates to true.
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Azure Sphere SDK Preview for Visual Studio'
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleManufacturer' to value 'Microsoft Corporation'
[56EC:3690][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i000: Setting numeric variable 'WixStdBALanguageId' to value 1033
[56EC:3690][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i000: Setting version variable 'WixBundleFileVersion' to value '19.5.4.54816'
[56EC:3690][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i000: Visual Studio Instance: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Enterprise, Version 16.0.28803.352
[56EC:3690][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2019_16_0_P2_Available' to value 1
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i100: Detect begin, 11 packages
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i000: Product or related product not found: {D0C37DF0-56F6-4D80-BDFC-74EEB20F578D}
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i000: Setting version variable 'installedExtensionVersion' to value '0.0.0.0'
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i000: Setting string variable 'WindowsBuildNumber' to value '17763'
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i000: Setting string variable 'NETFRAMEWORK45' to value '461814'
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i000: Setting version variable 'vsixInstallerVersion' to value '16.0.2264.33499'
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i052: Condition 'NETFRAMEWORK45 >= 461808' evaluates to true.
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i052: Condition 'NOT (WixBundleAction = 3 AND WixBundleUILevel = 1)' evaluates to true.
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i052: Condition 'NOT (WixBundleAction = 3 AND WixBundleUILevel = 1)' evaluates to true.
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i052: Condition '(WixBundleAction=3) AND (NOT WixBundleUILevel=1)' evaluates to false.
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i052: Condition '(WixBundleAction=3) AND (NOT WixBundleUILevel=1)' evaluates to false.
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i101: Detected package: NetFx472Redist, state: Present, cached: None
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i101: Detected package: ConnectedServiceLegacyUninstallQuiet, state: Present, cached: None
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i101: Detected package: ConnectedServiceUninstallQuietV16, state: Present, cached: None
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i101: Detected package: VSExtensionVSIXV15, state: Absent, cached: None
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i101: Detected package: VSExtensionVSIXV16, state: Absent, cached: None
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i101: Detected package: TapDriverInstaller, state: Absent, cached: None
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i101: Detected package: AzureSphereCore, state: Absent, cached: None
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i101: Detected package: SlipService, state: Absent, cached: None
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i101: Detected package: Sysroot_index0, state: Absent, cached: None
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i101: Detected package: Sysroot_index1, state: Absent, cached: None
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i101: Detected package: Sysroot_index2, state: Absent, cached: None
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i052: Condition 'WindowsBuildNumber >= 14393' evaluates to true.
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i052: Condition 'VS2017_15_9_Available OR VS2019_16_0_4_Available' evaluates to false.
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]e000: This product requires Visual Studio 2017, Version 15.9 or newer.
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]e000: Error 0x81f40001: Bundle condition evaluated to false: VS2017_15_9_Available OR VS2019_16_0_4_Available
[56EC:1244][2019-06-09T11:13:27]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
```

Do you have any recommendation?  Thank you

Comment: The error indicates you are running and older version of Visual Studio 2019. Can you double-check you have at least 16.0.4? If not, please run the Visual Studio Installer to update to the current version.

Comment: That's what it was!  Thank you very much.

Comment: Let me post this as answer, so we can get this question closed. Please mark as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When used with VS 2019 the Azure Sphere SDK requires patch level 16.0.4 or higher. If you are running an earlier version or a preview of VS 2019 please run the Visual Studio Installer to update VS to a current version.